# Symfony 2 FosUserBundle: "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I've got this error while trying to go to my WebSite using Symfony II production mode (it works in DEV mode)

SF log error: 
CRITICAL

> The class 'Camplica\UserBundle\Entity\User' was not found in the chain
>   configured namespaces FOS\UserBundle\Entity. I can't make my website
>   working..

It works great when I go to my website using dev' mode, but it's not working while using production mode.
I can't solve my problem, I can't see where does it come from.

**app/config/routing.yml**

```
camplica_home:
    resource: "@CamplicaHomeBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /CamPlica

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /CamPlica/profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /CamPlica/register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /CamPlica/resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /CamPlica/change-password
# Internal routing configuration to handle ESI
#_internal:
#    resource: "@FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/routing/internal.xml"
#    prefix:   /_internal
```

**Camplica/UserBundle/Entity/User.php**

```
<?php
// src/Sdz/UserBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace Camplica\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Entity\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="Camplica_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{

//....

}
```

**app/AppKernel.php**

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(
            new Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle(),
            new Symfony\Bundle\AsseticBundle\AsseticBundle(),
            new Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle(),
            new Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle(),
            new JMS\AopBundle\JMSAopBundle(),
            new JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle($this),
            new JMS\SecurityExtraBundle\JMSSecurityExtraBundle(),
            **new Camplica\UserBundle\CamplicaUserBundle(),**
            new Camplica\HomeBundle\CamplicaHomeBundle(),
            new FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle(),
        );

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
            $bundles[] = new Acme\DemoBundle\AcmeDemoBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
            $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

Edit: 
I don't know if it's related to my critical error but I got this in my log file.
request.INFO: Matched route "Index" (parameters: "_controller": "Camplica\HomeBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "Index") [] []

After clearing the cache.. I still get the same error :(

Comment: have you cleared cache for prod environment?

Comment: @Ferhad Yes I did it one more time to be sure.. Same error.

Comment: Use smallcaps in your routes, please.